# RadioButton behavior in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, radio-button, tablelayoutpanel

I am using a TableLayoutPanel and anchor property in order to make a window application that will look good independent to the screen resolution or to the form resize. 
I referred to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842418/Designing-the-Layout-of-Windows-Forms-using-a) in order to design the winform.

I have 3 `RadioButtons` on my form. Until working without `TableLayoutPanel`, the `RadioButtons` behave as per my expectation. Checking one `RadioButton`, unchecking the 2 other ones.
After adding each `RadioButton`  into different cell of the `TableLayoutPanel`, the `RadioButtons` behavior changed. Checking a `RadioButton`  doesn't uncheck the other ones.

[image]

Is there any property (group property) that I could set to have the 3 `RadioButtons` working together?

Comment: I tried to create a simple winforms project (.net 4.0 and .net 4.5), but no repro. can you post code, that designer generated (from `InitializeComponent()`)?

Comment: @Ash, I will need to prepare a small example since I had posted only a part of the form. Posting all InitializeComponent() will be too much to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say that the key to a good solution is that you keep up the visual paradigm of buttons that belong to **one** group; the user must not be surprised by `RadioButtons` that interact although they are far apart from each other.. But your layout seems to take care of that alright.

Probably for that very reason there is no property that would allow grouping RBs randomly..

Here is a helper class that manages `RadioButtons` indepently of their containers..:

```
class RadioCtl
{
    private List<RadioButton> buttons { get; set; }
    private bool auto = false;

    public RadioCtl()  { buttons = new List<RadioButton>(); }

    public int  RegisterRB(RadioButton rb)
    {
        if (!buttons.Contains(rb))
        {
            buttons.Add(rb);
            rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged;
        }
        return buttons.IndexOf(rb);
    }

    void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rbClicked = sender as RadioButton;
        if (rbClicked == null || auto) return;

        auto = true;
        foreach (RadioButton rb in buttons)
        {
            if ((rb != rbClicked)  && (rb.Parent != rbClicked.Parent) ) 
               rb.Checked = false;
        }
        auto = false;
    }

    public void UnregisterRB(RadioButton rb)
    {
        if (buttons.Contains(rb))
        {
            buttons.Remove(rb);
            rb.CheckedChanged -= rb_CheckedChanged;
        }
    }

    public void Clear() {  foreach(RadioButton rb in buttons) UnregisterRB(rb); }

    public int IndexOfRB(RadioButton rb)  { return buttons.IndexOf(rb); }
}
```

To use it you need to register each `RadioButton` you want to participate in the 'virtual group'..:

```
static RadioCtl RbCtl = new RadioCtl();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    RbCtl.RegisterRB(radioButton1);
    RbCtl.RegisterRB(radioButton2);
    RbCtl.RegisterRB(radioButton3);
    RbCtl.RegisterRB(radioButton4);
    RbCtl.RegisterRB(radioButton5);
}
```

You can unregister or re-register any `RadioButton` at any time or find the index in the group.

Also note that this only supports **one** group of `RadioButtons`. If you need more, either use a second object or expand the class to allow several, maybe named groups. You could replace the `List` by a `Dictionary` for this and expand the signatures and the code a little..

Comment: Thank you, elegant way to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Put all radio buttons for a group in a container object like a `Panel` or a `GroupBox`. That will automatically group them together.

Comment: I need them in different cells in the TableLayoutPanel. How can they belong to a same Panel or GroupBox within different cells? Thank you

Comment: Normally TableLayoutPanel is also a conteneurs control,so he must work as you want,try to delete yours radio buttons ,and drag one by one in your rows of tableLayou

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I presume that the reason is because the cells are also containers by themselves. Adding radio button to each cell will behave like adding to radio button 2 different group boxes.

Comment: @ehh It cannot be forced.  You are obviously concerned about layout, but you will have to find another way to synthesize the arrangement you are after while keeping the radio buttons in the same container.  Or forego all of the stock behaviors and code it all by hand, your choice.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, I cannot see any soultion apart coding as you mentioned